# How to remove, replace or substring a string from (the response of reading from serial port) the number of lines displayed in textbox

Tags: c#, serial-port, substring, z-index

```
namespace ProjectOne
{
 public partial class MainForm : Form
 {
  private void StatusBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //command sent to serial port and responds a series of lines
 string StatusInfoToshow = "?D\r";
 string commForMeter = string.Format(StatusInfoToshow);

 try
 {
  if (statusofMeter.serialPortForApp.IsOpen)
     {

        bool doesContain = commForMeter.Contains("\r");

                if (doesContain)
                {
                    foreach (char s in commForMeter)
                    {

 currentDataToShow.serialPortForApp.Write(s.ToString());
                    }
                }
     }
 }
 catch (Exception)
 {
     statusofMeter.ShowDataInScreenTxtb.Text = "TimeOUT Exception";
 }
}

int LineCounter= 0;

public void SerialPortInApp_DataReceived(object 
sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs 
e) 
{

DataToSetandGet = serialPortForApp.ReadExisting();
  int stratstring = 3;
int endstring = DataToSetandGet.LastIndexOf('\r');
int lenghtsub = endstring - stratstring;
string clash = DataToSetandGet.Substring(stratstring, lenghtsub );                                

 ShowDataInScreenTxtb.AppendText(clash.ToString().Replace("\n", " 
 ").Replace("\r", "\r\n"));
//I have this error
//System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'startIndex cannot be larger than 
 // length of string.Parameter name: startIndex'
 }
}
}
```

if I implement this:

```
int LineCounter= 0;
public void SerialPortInApp_DataReceived(object sender, 
SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   try
 {
   DataToSetandGet = serialPortForApp.ReadExisting();
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
//I  insert the the increment numbering index for each new line displayed 
//in the  textbox but index start at 0 not 1, if I set LineCounter=1 it 
//print 1 instead of 0 and the 1 again for next line
 Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { 
 Textbox_One.AppendText(LineCounter.ToString() +
            DataToSetandGet.Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", "\r\n")); 
      }));                                
 }
catch (Exception)
{
  Textbox_One.Text = "TimeOUT error";
 }
}
```

my button send a command to be listened in serial port and send an 
    answer. the responds in serial port will show records read from a sensor, 
    and each line(readings from sensor in device connected to port) always 
    start with a zero "0" string character at the beginning of each line. I 
    would like to Remove() or Substring() that zero "0" when it displays each 
    line.

```
//I cannot use Substring()

LineCounter.ToString()+ DataToSetandGet.Substring(n position in string)
```

because give me an error

```
//'startIndex cannot be larger than length of string:      
//this error is because it reads like:    
//0 record\r//0 record\r//0 record\r//0 record\r//0 record  

Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
Textbox1.AppendText(LineCounter.ToString()+ 
  DataToSetandGet.Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", "\r\n"));
 }));
```

The "\r" carriage return is because the command

```
//before using LineCounter it displays
//0 record
//0 record
//0 record
//0 record
//0 record
```

after using counter it displays:How to position index to start at 1 
 instead of 0 and next line as one

```
//1 0 record <==if LineCounter=1 but if LineCounter=0 it set first line 
//1 0 record 
//2 0 record
//3 0 record
//4 0 record
```

correct display should be like: How to Implement Substring() or Remove()

```
//1 record
//2 record
//3 record
//4 record
//5 record
```

Comment: You do not need, and shouldn't put [tags in your question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles). The tagging system is more than adequate (the little blue things at the bottom of your question). Also see the help on [tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): "The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title." (it includes a list of formats you shouldn't use if you include tags in your title, which includes [tag] [question title])

Comment: I've added an answer for you. In future, I recommend creating an [mcve]. Your question has a lot of secondary information which isn't relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your question is simply asking how to use `Substring`. You've stated that you receive the following error:

> startIndex cannot be larger than length of string

This is telling you that in `str.Substring(idx)`, `idx >= str.Length`.

To resolve this you can simply perform the following evaluation:

```
LineCounter.ToString() + (DataToSetandGet.Length > n ? DataToSetandGet.Substring(n) : string.Empty);
```

Which will use `Substring` where the length of the string permits, or otherwise return an empty string. Or you can use some other evaluation to ensure that idx isn't more than the `length of the string - 1` (indexes are 0-based).

Comment: @JimB Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the). It's because you're trying to update a UI component from a different thread to the UI thread.

Comment: @JimB Not sure what's wrong there. I recommend asking a new question about it - it's been some time since I worked with WinForms I'm afraid.

Comment: I recommend asking a new question. It really isn't related to this question and it's not my area of expertise.